# Cannot read property from .env in +server.ts

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, sveltekit

Using SveletKit I need to store a hashed password in my `.env` and use it in a `+server.ts`

The value comes as an empty string when reading it.

The `.env` looks like this.

```
ADMIN=adminusername
HASHED_PASSWORD="$2b$10$4bMzfiH59woVPnlijd21QeU9NYzaCIF2g0zypuNjxDU71m0MM8Fa2"
JWT_SECRET=BREUEnpzw9Jh79
```

I am importing them using

```
import { ADMIN, HASHED_PASSWORD, JWT_SECRET } from '$env/static/private';
```

I found that when using a shorter string as `HASHED_PASSWORD` like `foobar` it works perfectly fine.

Is there a maximal length for a string in a `.env`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` like `\$`

`HASHED_PASSWORD=\$2b\$10\$4bMzfiH59woVPnlijd21QeU9NYzaCIF2g0zypuNjxDU71m0MM8Fa2`

Using the above in the `.env` should work.

[Sandbox here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-rz35xp)